# Open to today's date within multiple tabs in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use this code for my sheet but I'm having a problem. I have 12 tabs in one sheet. Each table represents a new month. I would like it to auto jump to the current date in the corresponding tab.

My dates start in H1 and go till AL1.

I have tried adjusting the script to reflect that but with little success

```
   function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("H1:AL1");   // get all 2nd row
  var values = range.getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000;  
  var now = Date.now();  
  var ssdate; 
  for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    try {
      ssdate = values[0][i].getTime();
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    if (ssdate && ssdate <= now && now < ssdate + day) {
      sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));
      break;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump to the current date"?

Comment: Each tab has the days of its respected month from H1 to AL1. So on March 4th, when I open the sheet I would like it to jump to the Third tab and go to march 4th which is this case would be K1

Answer (score 0):

For this solution I suppose you have all the months ordered from January to December, so January is in the first position.

You can set a new Date every time you open the Spreadsheet, get the Month and Day and use `active` in the Sheets and Range:

```
function onOpen(){

  let date = new Date();
  let month = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'M');
  let day = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'd');

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  sheets[month - 1].activate();

  var range = sheets[month - 1].getRange(1, 7 + parseInt(day));
  sheets[month - 1].setActiveRange(range);

}
```

You will notice the  `7 + parseInt(day)`. Since H starts at the 8th position, we add the days of the current month, but deducing 1. Otherwise the first day of the month would be 8 + 1 (H + 1) and it would focus on I. Also, the `parseInt` is to convert `day` to an integer to avoid `7 + 6 = 76`.

**References**:

- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Sheet Activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())
- [Get Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))