# Going to sheet based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet for every day. Example:  3 january 2022 > sheet name is 3/01/2022

When I open the google spreadsheet file, I want the active sheet is the sheet of the actual date. So when opening the spreadsheet on 5 january 2022, the active sheet 5/1/2022 should be in front of me.

How do I do that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145827/how-to-open-a-specific-tab-based-on-todays-date-google-sheets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496802/open-to-todays-date-within-multiple-tabs-in-a-sheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213555/google-apps-spreadsheet-open-specific-sheet-based-on-current-date-month

Answer (score 0):

#### Get Sheet by Date

```
function onOpen() {
  gotoPage();
}

function gotoPage() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const name = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  sh.activate();
}
```

It's kind of slow getting there but it works for me.